# How to Call api on Keypress in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to fire a API call when user click (on key-press event) on textbox, how can I do it Angular. I am getting error with debounce method `Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined`

**app.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {

    this.searchField.valueChanges

        .pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            map((val) => {
                this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/articles/articleslistData', { pubid: '3', pubdate: this.dateChanged }).subscribe({
                    next: data => {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: error => {
                        this.errorMessage = error.message;
                        console.error('There was an error!', error);
                    }
                })
            })
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="form-field col-lg-12">
<label class="label" for="message">Headline</label>
<input id="message" class="input-text js-input" type="text" required [formControl]="searchField">
</div>
```

Comment: Where and how do you initialize your `this.searchField` ? it seems your propertie is not initialized

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Please watch your tongue brother

Comment: @Lautre I initalise my this.searchField  before constructor `searchField: FormControl;`
Please guide if I went something worng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your form control either in the ngOnInit or in the propertie declaration.

```
export class MyClass {
  // solution 1
  public searchField = new FormControl({});
  ngOnInit() {
      // solution 2
      this.searchField = new FormControl({});
      // your code here
  }
}
```

You can also use the FormBuild class
For more information

See: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#initializing-form-controls

Comment: yes it works but in my textbox field it shows `[object object]` only, though my api contains 2 values only `ArticleID` and `Title`

Comment: it depends on what you want to do, in your question I didn't see any thin on setting the field value. But the input shoulld contains only primitive data like `string`, `number` etc... if you have `[object object]` it means you put as input value the full object `{ArticleID: any; Title: any}`.

Comment: it didn't work still getting `[object object]` you got minute please help!

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with the reproductible error

Answer (score 1):

Futhermore,you need use switchMap (switchMap "reemplace" one observable by another one) some like

```
this.searchField.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap ((val) => {
          //we can not return the "val", else
          //the result of this.http.post
          // here you has "val", I suppose i your call
          // you use it
        return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/articles/articleslistData', { pubid: '3', pubdate: this.dateChanged })
    })
).subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data);
},
error => {
  this.errorMessage = error.message;
  console.error('There was an error!', error);
}
);
```

see that you has only one subscription